# How do I bind an NSTableColumn to NSArrayController arrangedObjects programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, binding, nsarraycontroller, nstablecolumn

So i have an `NSTableView` with dynamic `NSTableColumns`. The columns should get it's data from an NSArrayController's arrangedObject.

Since everything is dynamic, I can't really use the interface builder to bind values.
How do I do this programmatically?

I tried this:

```
NSTableColumn *newColumn = [[NSTableColumn alloc]initWithIdentifier:aKey];
[newColumn.value bind:@"value" toObject:arrayController.arrangedObjects withKeyPath:aKey options:nil];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay i figured it out..

```
NSString *akey = @"somekey";
NSString *keypath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"arrangedObjects.%@",akey];
[newColumn bind:@"value" toObject:arrayController withKeyPath:keypath options:nil];
```

Comment: I am working on NSTablecolumn Sorting. I am not able find code, please post complete code